# For the `angularjs-gulp-example` project, why does `gulp bower` work, despite `bower.json` not being present?

Tags: npm, gulp, bower, gulp-bower

Reading https://github.com/jhades/angularjs-gulp-example/blob/master/gulpfile.js, but I am surprised to find that it runs although `bower.json` is not even present! I can't see any error messages complaining about the missing file either.. what's going on!?

Answer (score 0):

`gulp-install` is being used here to install "bower" dependencies. However the docs at https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-install specify ...

> Automatically install npm, bower, tsd, and pip packages/dependencies
>   if the relative configurations are found in the gulp file stream
>   respectively

... only "if the relative configurations are found", will the installation take place. In this case, `bower.json` is simply not present and so relatively nothing will be installed!